# Importing "stem and plot" type data into scala and storing in tuples

Tags: scala, mapreduce, tuples

I have been given data in a format similar to a stem and leaf plot in a txt file. It has a user id and then the list of friends associated, separated by a tab. e.g

```
-0 tab 3,4,2,5,6

-1 tab 5,2,8

-2 tab 0,1,7,8,5
```

I need this in scala in a way that I end up with a tuple of `(userid, friend)` for each of the values. So, for `0` i would need `(0,3)`, `(0,4)`, `(0,2)`, `(0,5)`, and `(0,6)`. This is for a map reduce type deal. What I have so far does not work and is probably not even close:

```
def parseLine(line:String) = {
  val fields = line.split("\t")
  val userID = fields(0).toInt
  val userlist = List(userID)
  val friends = fields(1).split(",")
  for (x <- userlist){
    val user = x
    for (y <- friends){
      val friendID = y
      (userID, friendID)
    }
  } 
}
```

any help would be much appreciated thank you !

Update: Thanks for all the help so far. I'm getting somewhere, but I'm still having some trouble. I'm going to put my full code so far below. Again, any help is very appreciated. Thanks guys.

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j._
import scala.io.Source
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction
import scala.io.Codec
import scala.math.sqrt
import java.io._

object FriendRec {
  def parseLine(line: String) = {
    val fields = line.split("\t")
    val userID = fields(0).toInt
    val friends = fields(1).split(",")
    for (friendID <- friends) 
      yield (userID, friendID)
    }

  //** Our main function where the action happens *//
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

// Set the log level to only print errors
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

// Create a SparkContext using every core of the local machine
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "FriendRec")

// Load each line of the source data into an RDD
    val lines = sc.textFile("../input-f.txt")

// Use our parseLines function to convert to (age, numFriends) tuples
    val rdd = lines.map(parseLine)
    rdd.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for comprehension instead of a regular for loop.

```
def parseLine(line: String) = {
  val fields = line.split("\t")
  val userID = fields(0).toInt
  val friends = fields(1).split(",")
  for (friendID <- friends) yield (userID, friendID)
} // Array[Tuple[Int, String]]

val result = parseLine("0\t3,4,2,5,6")
// Array((0,3), (0,4), (0,2), (0,5), (0,6))
```